Post having issues with images. Is this caused by the change of image hosting?
On Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice it was asked to make a post to report issues with image hosting. I just found a recent self-answered Q&A having images hosted on the new provider i.sstatic.net but I'm unsure if the images problems are caused by the hosting
The question is Table of Contents page numbers wrong. It has post notice saying that it was migrated from Super User three hours ago. Below there is a screenshot of the question, showing the icon for missing images.



Both question and answer have one missing image.
Note: I'm not on my usual Internet connection, I'm using the connection from a restaurant.
Update: I'm now on my usual Internet connection. The images are working fine.

This seems to be the same issue described in this Meta SE post: Images from i.sstatic.net only work for me after being accessed from another IP address

Same exact thing, the last image in each (and variants with s/m/l size adjustments) wasn't loading, but it is now.

Images are working fine on my side:


Works fine here too. Might be an ISP issue: Images from i.sstatic.net only work for me after being accessed from another IP address
